# How can I easily visualize my data sent over MQTT with AWS IoT Core

Tags: amazon-web-services, iot

I'm evaluating AWS IoT Services, and sending `cpu_usage` and `available_memory` for a Gateway.

I would like to visualize the data on a graph.

Using AWS IoT SDK, I can easy send data over MQTT to AWS IoT Core.

But then, I have no idea how to visualize the data.

I have seen [this tuto](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/build-a-visualization-and-monitoring-dashboard-for-iot-data-with-amazon-kinesis-analytics-and-amazon-quicksight/) from AWS that use Kinesis Firehose/Analytics and QuickSight to visualize data, but it just seems too much (and too expensive) for my use case.

I have also seen [this tuto](https://hub.packtpub.com/build-an-iot-application-with-aws-iot-tutorial/) that use ELK to visualize the data, but really, I have no money to spend on a dedicated ELK instance just to visualize little data.

I tried to send data to CloudWatch using a Rule, but with query:

```
SELECT free_memory FROM topic_1
```

But I can't see this metric.

I also asked for AWS IoT Graph preview access hoping it will resolve my issue, but I am right now a bit lost.

Is there an easy / free tier compatible way to visualize data from IoT devices ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to have IoT feed into CloudWatch. You can then configure a nice dashboard for your data:

[image: AWS CloudWatch dashboard]

I have an ESP8266 running Mongoose OS which is feeding in temperature data from a DHT11. The JSON being put onto MQTT looks like:

```
{
  "total_ram": 51600,
  "free_ram": 39584,
  "temp": 16,
  "humidity": 64
}
```

I then have a rule with the query:

```
SELECT * FROM '/devices/esp8266_079110/events'
```

Then two actions, one for temperature and one for humidity. They look something like:

[image: value: ${temp}]

And your data then goes into CloudWatch. You can hit the Dashboard section in the AWS Console, create a new one and interactively add line graphs, latest values, etc.

It took a while to configure this. I had some validation issues when first creating the rule actions but I was able to resolve them after enabling logging in the settings for IoT then AWS said exactly what I screwed up.

Despite how much time I spent on this, there's only 2 systems involved: IoT and CloudWatch. I'm very happy with how simple this is.